# Java beginer - Arrays - how to print a sorted array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Problem: when printing a sorted array with data type "int" it is returning funny character "[I@edf4efb". It looks like the address of the array

Question: how to print a sorted array?

```
Code listed below:

import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [] sa = {8,200,10};
  Arrays.sort(sa);
  Arrays.sort(sa);
  System.out.println(sa);
}
```

Actual result:
[I@edf4efb

Expected result:
8, 10, 200

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409795/6383857) out

Answer (score 1):

Use [Arrays toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(boolean[]))

```
Arrays.toString()

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(income));
```

Comment: Anyone can help me with my extended question so that I can understand fully on "why do we need to use for loop to print out a sorted array? However, I don't need a for loop to print a specific index from an array, though... example `int [] sa = {8,200,10};` `System.out.println("The 2nd index for sa array is: " + sa[1]);` kindly help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected programme

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sa = { 8, 200, 10 };
        Arrays.sort(sa);
        for (int i = 0; i < sa.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(sa[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you all. @tarun, I have not pick up "for" loop tutorial yet. so whey do we need to use for loop to print out a sorted array? for an example, if i want to print a specific index from an array, i dont have to need to use it though... example `int [] sa = {8,200,10};`
  `System.out.println("The 2nd index for sa array is: " + sa[1]);`